# setUp(scenarios.AppiumTest): A new session could not be created

Tags: android

I am new to appium and I am trying to run a basic project and I a getting the below error:

```
setUp(scenarios.AppiumTest): A new.   session could not be created. (Original error: Bad app: D:\MyProject\apps\Flipkart.3.0.apk. App paths need to be absolute, or relative to the appium server install dir, or a URL to compressed file, or a special app name. cause: Error: Error locating the app: ENOENT, stat 'D:\MyProject\apps\Flipkart.3.0.apk') (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 229 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.46.0', revision: '61506a4624b13675f24581e453592342b7485d71', time: '2015-06-04 10:22:50'
System info: host: 'NODE211', ip: '192.168.47.1', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Driver info:       io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
```

Below is the code that I am using.

```
package scenarios;


import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;


public class AndroidSetup {
    protected AndroidDriver driver;

    protected void prepareAndroidForAppium() throws MalformedURLException {
File appDir = new File("D:/MyProject/apps");
        File app = new File(appDir, "Flipkart.3.0.apk");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("device","Android");

        //mandatory capabilities`enter code here`
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");

        //other caps
        capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
        driver =  new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    }
}
```

Please help me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should give the path of the file as:

```
"D:\\MyProject\\apps"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the proper .apk path and use the following code

> File classPathRoot = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
>
> File appDir = new File(classPathRoot, "/");
>
> File app = new File(appDir, ".apk");
>
> app.getAbsolutePath();

Please try with the above piece of code.